# MYSQLi query not producing expected results

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having a problem getting results I can use from my query. Code:

```
    //Create query
$stmt = $con->stmt_init();
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `userlogin` = '$username' AND `user_passwrd` = sha1(CONCAT('$userpw', `stamp`))"; 
$result = $con->query($query);
$rows = array();
if($stmt->prepare($query)) {
    if($stmt->execute()) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_array()) { 
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
    }
}
$result->free();
var_dump($row); //Returns NULL
die();
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$ulogin = $row['userlogin'];
$pending = $row['pending'];
$acclvl = $row['user_accesslevel'];
```

I can get results with var_dump($rows) but I'm obviously doing something wrong here. I am unable to populate the variables and don't know why. Any help would be appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping through the resulting rows until there are not more results and `fetch_array()` (and thereby `$row`) is NULL;

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) { 
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

...so...

```
var_dump($row); //Returns NULL
```

...is hardly a surprise anymore :)

A simple way to do this would be something like this (can't test run this, so see more as a hint, and you *should* really parameterise your query)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `userlogin` = '$username' AND `user_passwrd` = sha1(CONCAT('$userpw', `stamp`))"; 
$result = $con->query($query);
if(!$result)
   die("horribly");
$row = $result->fetch_array()
$result->free();
```

Comment: Could you show me how I might correct this. I've googled and googled and don't seem to be able to come up with a workable solution. I'm very new at this. Cheers